# How to read a GZIP payload in Ruby Sinatra

Tags: ruby, curl, sinatra, gzip, zlib

On a remote host I have a bash script sending a simple gzipped YAML file to my Ruby Sinatra endpoint:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/gzip -c /tmp/test.yaml > /tmp/test.gz

curl -i <hostname>:<port>/last_run_report -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --data-binary @/tmp/test.gz
```

My sample Ruby app is:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'zlib'
require 'stringio'

set :port, <port>
set :bind, "<ip>"

post '/last_run_report' do
  sio = StringIO.new(request.body.to_s)
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(sio).read
  test_yaml = YAML.load(gz)
end
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Zlib::GzipFile::Error: not in gzip format
```

If I require 'base64' and change the endpoint definition to:

```
post '/last_run_report' do
  raw = Base64.decode64(request.body)
  sio = StringIO.new(raw)
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(sio).read
  test_yaml = YAML.load(gz)
end
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `unpack1' for #<StringIO:0x000055713e2d51b8>
```

I can't figure out if I'm sending the data wrong or reading it wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a YAML sample like the following:

```
martin:
    name: Martin D'vloper
    job: Developer
    skill: Elite
```

You don't need all the excess `StringIO` stuff. `request.body` is already a `StringIO` instance, so converting it to a string then converting that to a `StringIO` is unnecessary:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'zlib'

post '/last_run_report' do
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(request.body).read
  puts YAML.load(gz)
end
```

Now make your request:

```
curl -i localhost:4567/last_run_report -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --data-binary @test.gz
```

And view the sinatra output:

```
== Sinatra (v2.0.4) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
{"martin"=>{"name"=>"Martin D'vloper", "job"=>"Developer", "skill"=>"Elite"}}
::1 - - [14/Jan/2019:23:24:28 -0700] "POST /last_run_report HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0048
```

Note that `puts` has written `{"martin"=>{"name"=>"Martin D'vloper", "job"=>"Developer", "skill"=>"Elite"}}` to the console.

I should point out that in your example the following code does not work the way you expect:

```
sio = StringIO.new(request.body.to_s)
```

You expect to be able to call `sio.read` and get something like this:

```
\x1F\x8B\b\b\xA7z=\\\x00\x03test.yaml\x00SVp\xCCSH\xCD-\xC8\xC9\xAFLMU(JM\xCE/J\xE1\xCAM,*\xC9\xCC\xB3\xE2R\x00\x82\xBC\xC4\xDCT+\x05_\xB0\x88\x82\x8BzYN~Aj\x11X&+?\xC9J\xC1%\xB5,\x15!T\x9C\x9D\x99\x93c\xA5\xE0\x9A\x93Y\x92\n\x00\xFC\xA0\x83yZ\x00\x00\x00
```

What you in fact get is this:

```
#<StringIO:0x00007ffd8184bdf0>
```

Note that this is the literal string "`#<StringIO:0x00007ffd8184bdf0>`" and not a reference to a `StringIO` object, because that is what is returned when calling `.to_s` on a `StringIO` object like `request.body`, so any subsequent call to `sio.read` (which is implicit in the call to `Zlib::GzipReader.new`) will return that literal string and will not return the gzipped data that you expect it to return, which leads to the error `Zlib::GzipFile::Error: not in gzip format`.

When you want to return the string representation of a `StringIO` you should call [`.string`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-string) or [`.read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/IO.html#method-i-read), not `.to_s`. With that in mind, the minimal change required to make your first example work is to change this:

```
sio = StringIO.new(request.body.to_s)
```

To this:

```
sio = StringIO.new(request.body.string)
```

But again, this is an unnecessary conversion of a `StringIO` to a string and back to a `StringIO`.